# mysql 404 error post

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a simple online art store. A part of the site is a registration feature that allows users to register. I am using MySQL for the database. The registration page has a form where the user fills in basic information. The php script is in a separate php file named "registerAction.php". However, when the submit button is pressed, I get a 404 error saying the file with the php script cannot be found.

Here is the portion of the code for the register form:

```
<table class="registerField">
        <form method="post" action="registerAction.php" >
        <tr>
            <td class="query">
                Username:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="field" name="UserName">
            </td>
            <td class="help">Longer than 5 characters, cannot start with a number.</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="query">
                Name:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="field" name="RealName"
            </td>
            <td class="help">Your Name </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="query">
                Password:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" class="field" name="Password">
            </td>
            <td class="help">Longer than 6 characters.</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="query">
                Confirm password:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" class="field" name="RePassword">
            </td>
            <td class="help">Re-enter password.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td><input type ="submit" value="Submit</td>
        </tr>
        </form>
    </table>
```

Here is the code for the registerAction.php:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','Users');

$UName=$_POST['UserName'];
$RName=$_POST['RealName'];
$Password=$_POST['Password'];
$RePassword=$_POST['RePassword'];

if(!$con){
    echo "CONNECTION ERROR";
}

if(!mysqli_select_db($con,'Users')){
    echo "DATABASE ERROR";
}


$sql="INSERT INTO Users (UserName,Password,RealName) VALUES('$UName','$Password','RName')";

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
echo"ERROR";
}else{
    echo"REGISTRATION SUCCESSFUL";
}
```

why is it that the browser cannot find the registerAction.php file? Both the registration form and the registrationAction.php are in the same folder. If it is of any significance, I am using XAMPP for MySQL and the coding is done in PHPStorm.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is URL when you're on form page ? and What is the URL when you submit the form ?

Comment: check for permissions, also can you nav directly to the registerAction.php ? as you writed, remember case

Comment: what is your original page with form link look like?

Comment: @QuijoteShin what do you mean by check for permission?

Comment: @LorenceHernandez a 404, may be if apache can't see the file or you can't find a file becouse is not on that path. do this rename index.php to index.back, to allow apache list the files for,  you should see the dir index

Comment: @QuijoteShin isee i thought u were talking about some kind of permission

Comment: not to you directly  but to the files xD jeje

Comment: `<input type="text" class="field" name="RealName"` is an error. You are open to SQL injections as well.

Comment: @Alok the url for the form page is     localhost:59197/artStore/register.php?_ijt=lenmf9bqq18lbb6iahberf1er1  

and after submitting it is localhost:59197/artStore/registerAction.php  
Both of the pages are within the same folder

Comment: @QuijoteShin Do you mean to change the .php portion of the page with the form in to .back?  
Sorry I'm a beginner in PHP,couldnt get what you said about the checking for permission.

Comment: @chris85 how did I miss that..thanks a lot. I'll correct that right away.

Comment: @QuijoteShin and yes, I can directly access registerAction.php. The page just shows some PHP errors though.

Comment: I found out what I was doing wrong. Apparently, you need to load the webpages directly through localhost and not through PHPStorm. Its working perfectly now. Thank you all for your answers and sorry for making a problem out of something that did not exist in the first place.  So, how do I close this thread?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form method="post" action="registerAction.php">
```

base on your code, the registerAction.php file must be in the same folder with your registration form file

Comment: they are in the same folder